# JSON Path not working properly with athena

Tags: jsonpath, amazon-athena, aws-glue

I have a lambda function that converts my logs to this format:

```
{
    "events": [
        {
            "field1": "value",
            "field2": "value",
            "field3": "value"
        }, (...)
    ]
}
```

When I query it on S3, I get in this format:

```
[
    {
        "events": [
            { (...) }
        ]
    }
]
```

And I'm trying to run a custom classifier for it because the data I want is inside the objects kept by 'events' and not events itself.

So I started with the simplest path I could think that worked in my tests (https://jsonpath.curiousconcept.com/)

```
$.events[*]
```

And, sure, worked in the tests but when I run a crawler against the file, the table created includes only an `events` field with a struct inside it.

So I tried a bunch of other paths:

```
$[*].events
$[*].['events']
$[*].['events'].[*]
$.[*].events[*]
$.events[*].[*]
```

Some of these does not even make sense and absolutely every one of those got me an schema with an `events` field marked as array.

Can anyone point me to a better direction to handle this issue?

Comment: Below you have the answers on the similar problems.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52031322/create-athena-table-from-nested-json-source/52081347#52081347

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51678474/issue-with-regexp-extract-function/52103045#52103045

Comment: I've found an similar answer before but didn't quite work... For SerDe to work properly I need to send all my data in one-record-per-line or it can query 'standard' JSON as well?

Comment: I have also considered leaving the data as it is, with an array of struct and maybe unpack it using a view but I find this a little cumbersome and I believe there must be a way to make jsonpath work properly...

Comment: Try this one: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52067065/aws-glue-custom-classifiers-json-path/52074078#52074078