# How to link JSON file in S3 bucket with field in AWS Athena

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, amazon-athena

I am trying to store some email information into Athena "subject, from, to, body" and for body, I will contain some large content in it.

Is it possible for me to link maybe a JSON or a TXT file in S3 bucket with the entry in the body column and pull that instead from Athena?

I have seen  that DynamoDB has something like this where it can store reference of objects in it's entries.

Can we do the same in Athena? If so, could someone point me to how we can store that information and retrieve that data?

Thank you

Nikhil

Answer (score 0):

Athena is Presto with some limitations. You can use Hive syntax and create a table directly in Athena or you can create a table by using Crawler from AWS Glue.

The links to the documentation:

https://docs.aws.amazon.com/athena/latest/ug/json.html

https://docs.aws.amazon.com/athena/latest/ug/querying-JSON.html

https://docs.aws.amazon.com/glue/latest/dg/add-crawler.html

My answers in the subject of Json and Athena:

[Create Athena table from nested json source](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52031322/create-athena-table-from-nested-json-source/52081347#52081347)

[AWS Glue Custom Classifiers Json Path](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52067065/aws-glue-custom-classifiers-json-path/52074078#52074078)